# django rest framework ListAPIView returning no value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django reset framework to create an API.

Here is my `Serializer.py`

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("title", "content")
```

`views.py`

```
class ArticleListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class ArticleDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

`urls.py`

```
from .views import ArticleListView, ArticleDetailView
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', ArticleListView.as_view() ),
        path('<pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view() ),
    ]
```

When I pull up `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/`, there are 3 objects of Article model in DB and all what I get is this:

```
 [ 
    {},
    {},
    {}
 ]
```

`models.py`

```
    class Article(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        content = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Why can't I see the values of the `title` and `content` of my class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a small typo in your code.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
```

should be:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

Note the "Model" that you are missing.
With regular `Serializer` you would need to define the fields explicitly while `ModelSerializer` will introspect the associated model.